# Change character to date with different format (Win and Mac)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several date variables in a data.frame.

They look for example like this:

```
[1] "10/14/18 17:55:28"        "10/15/18 19:27:56"       
  [3] "11/04/18 15:47:46"        "Thu Feb  7 14:51:55 2019"
  [5] "Thu Feb  7 17:14:15 2019" "Thu Feb  7 15:46:09 2019"
  [7] "Thu Feb  7 11:42:27 2019" "Thu Feb  7 13:24:16 2019"
  [9] "Thu Feb  7 18:02:29 2019" "Mon Oct 15 08:48:43 2018"
 [11] "10/17/18 17:08:38"        "12/08/18 08:08:11"       
 [13] "10/11/18 21:25:30"        "10/14/18 19:15:30"       
 [15] "10/16/18 11:18:01"        "10/16/18 18:19:27"       
 [17] "Tue Oct 16 19:49:24 2018" "Wed Oct 17 21:36:32 2018"
 [19] "Sat Oct 13 11:22:35 2018" "Fri Dec  7 17:12:33 2018"
```

At the moment this is a character variable. I want to change it with as.Date to substract the variables from each other.

I already found this:

```
as.Date( DATE$Sess1, format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

I would prefer to keep not only the date but also the time. 
The real problem is that they include Apple and Windows format which makes it even more complicated.

I would prefer dplyr solutions ;)

Comment: Use [strptime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime), with a condition on the format string (for instance, if the first character of the input is a letter) to distinguish both cases (assuming there are only two cases). *There is a special place in hell for those* who don't format dates consistently...

Comment: The dates come from different computers. So you have to blame the developers of apple and windows for that. Actually, they should collaborate ;)

Comment: Check out the `anytime` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lubridate`s `parse_date_time` and include all the formats that it could take.

```
x <- c("10/14/18 17:55:28" ,       "10/15/18 19:27:56" ,      
       "11/04/18 15:47:46" ,       "Thu Feb  7 14:51:55 2019",
       "Thu Feb  7 17:14:15 2019", "Thu Feb  7 15:46:09 2019")


lubridate::parse_date_time(x,c('mdyT', 'amdTY'))

#[1] "2018-10-14 17:55:28 UTC" "2018-10-15 19:27:56 UTC" "2018-11-04 15:47:46 UTC"
#[4] "2019-02-07 14:51:55 UTC" "2019-02-07 17:14:15 UTC" "2019-02-07 15:46:09 UTC"
```

Read `?parse_date_time` to know different format details.

To get the dates, you can wrap `as.Date` around it.

```
as.Date(lubridate::parse_date_time(x,c('mdyT', 'amdTY')))
#[1] "2018-10-14" "2018-10-15" "2018-11-04" "2019-02-07" "2019-02-07" "2019-02-07"
```

Answer (score 2):

For keeping the time, it's best to use a different date format, e.g. `POSIXlt` or `POSIXct`. You can also extend the format string to include the time (e.g. `format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"`) - see https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/strptime.html for more details on these codes.

```
as.POSIXlt(DATE$Sess1, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

As for handling different formats, because the ones you have aren't unambiguous on their own, I suggest having a vector of possible formats, then trying each in turn until one works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the tidyverse, use {lubridate} to reformat. There are two different date/time formats in your example, so you'll need to format them twice.

```
lubridate::as_datetime(DATE$Sess1, format = "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

and then for all the NA results...

```
lubridate::as_datetime(DATE$Sess1, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```